# Python: randint generates the upper limit of range required

Tags: python

I need to created a randomly ordered list of numbers from 0 to 9999
So here is my approach to do this:

```
order = list(range(10000));
rorder = [];
while (len(order) > 0):
    index_to_pop = random.randint(0,len(order));   
    print(str(index_to_pop) + " from list of size " + str(len(order)));
    rorder.append(order.pop(index_to_pop));
```

However this fails with the error

> pop index out of range

This is because the print statemente at a given point in the iteration gives:

> 7288 from list of size 7288

So... How can this be possible? According to the documentations randint should give me a number between 0 and len(order) -1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whatnow? [*"`random.randint(a, b)` - Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b."*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) If you want the range to be *exclusive*, you need to subtract 1 yourself.

Comment: You're reading the docs wrong. [`randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) includes the endpoint. As opposed to [`randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange).

Comment: Why should you reinvent the wheel? Use `random.sample(range(1, 10000), 10000)`.

Comment: why not use numpy for this? `order = np.arange(10000), rorder = np.random.shuffle(order)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong here: "According to the documentations randint should give me a number between 0 and len(order) -1."

The doc says: "random.randint(a, b). Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b. Alias for randrange(a, b+1)."

See it here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint

Comment: Got my docs from scypy. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html. Did not see that this was a different randint function. So it behaves differently. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using *shuffle* from module *random*. I think this is what you need:

```
import random

ordered = list(range(10000))
random.shuffle(ordered)
print(ordered)
```

Keep in mind that shuffle **does not return the shuffled list**. It is shuffeling the list you gave to it.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll use this instead! Still, I can't mark this answer as correct because it does not address my original question. But thank you anyways

Comment: you are welcome :) Your right! But i thought why not solving the main problem ;)